# Get value in form of !text plugin - Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using !text plugin of `require.js` to separate the template of `backbone` project in to html file.

Here is the `html` file :

```
<form>
<table style="padding-left:10px;">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter the service number : <br /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="servicenumber" style="height:24px;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="searchservice" value="Search" class="btn"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is the view :

```
define(["jquery" ,
"underscore" ,
"backbone" ,
"text!templates/Service/serviceTemplate.html",
"service"
],function($ , _ , Backbone, ServiceTagTem, Service){
   var service1 = new Service();

   var serviceTagLookUpView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize : function(){
      },
      event : {
        'click #searchservice' : 'searchService'
      },
      searchService : function(){
        console.log("this is "+$("#servicenumber").val());
        alert(1);
      },
      render : function(){
        var serviceTag = _.template(ServiceTagTem);
        this.$el.append(serviceTag);
      }
   });
   return serviceTagLookUpView;
});
```

The form views in my webpage, but when I viewed the source code, there's no form so the
`console.log("this is "+$("#servicenumber").val());` did not show in my console. Any idea ?

Comment: Have you called the `serviceTagLookUpView.render()` method ?

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE : I've called it in my router.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `el` element of your view :

```
var serviceTagLookUpView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#page', // give it an existing div in you page
  initialize : function(){
  },
  ...
```

---

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4y4bu/), when you comment the `el: '#page',` you view wont be rendered.

Comment: Did you html page contain a `<div id='page'></div>` ?

Comment: yes sure, when I viewed source code in my browser, div is exist.

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if it's the problem you have or not.

Comment: Covert html template to string?

Comment: Yes, that's what the require.js!text plugin do for you, except that he load it from the server.

Comment: But in that case, if I have many elements in my template, I think it is too hard to make it to string like that.

Comment: No no no, I don't mean convert your template to string, I do it just to run the example, because I can't use !text is jsfiddle.

Comment: The updated answer, I already tried, but about render(), I use it in my router not in the view. Is it could cause the problem?

Comment: No, you can call it wherever you want. Can you update the example with the exact problem ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48018/discussion-between-domo-and-rida-benhammane)